Can I apply usage qoutas in bigquery on table level rather than project level?
I work for a mid sized company using a GCP backend with dozens of datasets and tables/views that feed into looker dashboards- typically we use 50-60 dollars of big-query data per day for our looker dashboards since they run on top of GCP queries.   However occassionally there are some dashboards which can result in excessive number of TBs being used- up to 200 dollars per day for a heavy day of dashboard usage from our analysts- this is the number at which we cap our daily Big-query costs and after this our project doesnt let us run anymore queries to prevent runaway costs.   I am the data engineer for the backend and I have been working to try and cut costs- I have identified that there are 2 views in particular which have looker dashboards linked to them which are causing our costs to spike on some days.   I was wondering if there is a way to set a qouta for these specific views at say 10 dollars a day- this would be preferrable over having simply a qouta for the whole project because

It would be more effective at preventing excessive costs since sometimes just one view/dashboard can rack up 100 dollars of costs in a single day.
When the qouta is hit for the whole project it causes scheduled queries that are meant to run overnight to also fail- whereas if the individual views/tables hit their own limits but the overall porject limit wasnt hit then these scheduled queries would still be able to run without issues.

Is this something that is possible to do and if so what method would be most appropriate and what permissions do I need?
I tried analysing the security permissions on each table but as far as I can see while tou can give specific service accounts access to certain tables there isnt a way to limit the usage based on tables/service accounts

Consider creating a second (or more) projects in which to host the tables you want cost constrained.  I am imagining you have all your datasets and tables in one project and have a cost control on THAT project.  You want to constrain costs on queries against a subset of tables.  What you can do is move those tables to a new project and apply cost controls on THAT project.  What this will result in is a maximum cost for queries one set of tables and a separate maximum cost for queries on a separate set of tables.  If the quota is reached in one project, queries on the other project will still be permitted.
However, there may even be an easier way.  Since you are using Looker Studio, you can craft your own data source (see attached screen shot).  In the data source, you can explicitly specify a different project for billing.  It should be the case that the quotas on THAT project are used for BigQuery cost constraints.  So, again, you can create a project that contains nothing but a quota constraint and specify that as the Looker Studio billing project for some subset of data definitions.

